# Regular Expression To Replace Double Slashes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to remove any forward slashes in URL that are more than once in the sequence. So far:

```
var temp = "/path//to/middle//nowhre/avator2.jpg";
temp.replace(/\/\//,'/');
```

This works only for double slashes and only once but i would like it removes any number slashes that are more than once and do it for any occurance in the URL. I also tried

```
temp.replace(/*[/+]*/,'/');
```

but this doesn't work. Any help much appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all sequences of two or more `/` with a single `/`:
`temp.replace(/\/{2,}/g,'/');`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `g` (global modifier) to replace all occurrences. Use the following for two or more slashes.

```
var r = "/path//to/middle//nowhre/avator2.jpg".replace(/\/{2,}/g, '/');
console.log(r); //=> "/path/to/middle/nowhre/avator2.jpg"
```

Comment: Vow...so quick. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you should have global

```
temp.replace(/[\/]+/g, '/')
```

Answer (score 1):

For URL's, I suggest the following:

```
var s = "http://www.some-url.com//path//to";
var res = s.replace(/(https?:\/\/)|(\/)+/g, "$1$2");
```